# Limiting the access to /wp-admin/ for the whole server

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I want to limit the access to /wp-admin/ to specific IPs or even localhost

it's described here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Limit_Access_to_wp-admin_by_IP

but that seems to be for individual site

I want to make it server wide.

So obviosly i would put the .htaccess file in the main web dir but how to make the path so it affects */wp-admin/* for all sites below

Comment: Why don't you put it in the main apache config file? Location directive would be relative to sites.

Comment: ok that sounds smart
what should I put there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to the default apache configuration and these rules will apply to any site running in that server.

```
<Location /wp-admin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
    Allow from 10.1.1.0/16
    Deny from 192.168.1.1
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Comment: That seems like the smartest way! Thank you for that!
What happens if we have nginx running in front for static content and passing the dynamic one to apache behind?
Would that still work?

Comment: @Greg that depends on what apache sees for the ip address of the client. If apache only sees nginx local ip address, than this will not work and you will need to do a similar configuration on nginx.

Comment: Yeah makes sense Mehmet.
I guess it's just better to do it on the nginx side anyway for better performance?